# quota is needed by nfs-utils

Tags: software-installation, package-management, rpm

```
[root@cimnfsclient rajan]# rpm -i nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.68.el7.1.x86_64.rpm

error: Failed dependencies:
quota is needed by nfs-utils-1:1.3.0-0.68.el7.1.x86_64
```

I am not sure why i am getting this

```
hostnamectl
Static hostname: cimnfsclient
Icon name: computer-vm
Chassis: vm
Machine ID: 4f241c5567164542ad656857ca51ee58
Boot ID: 19f292b5bef4418eae63e0c1fb995cbb
Virtualization: vmware
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64
Architecture: x86-64
```

Answer (score 2):

RPM packages can depend upon other packages to provide necessary functionality (and most of them do). The `rpm` command cannot fetch these dependencies by itself, which is why the error is displayed. As a simple example, if foo.rpm requires 'bar' as a dependency, you need to get the appropriate bar.rpm and then install with `rpm -i foo.rpm bar.rpm`.

For this use case (package management), the common approach on CentOS 7 is to use `yum`, which presents a higher level abstraction compared to `rpm`. `yum` can resolve and fetch dependencies automatically, so you simply need to do `yum install nfs-utils`.

If you absolutely need to use `rpm` for this, you need a way to work out the dependency tree (since dependency packages can have their own dependencies) and then collect all of the necessary packages. This page should be a useful reference for the task (see the 'Requires' sub-section): https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.68.el7.x86_64.rpm.html